# MongoDB: $isolated with sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, sharding, transaction-isolation

The MongoDB docs [say](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/isolated/):

> $isolated does not work with sharded clusters

Does this mean it does **not work at all**? Or does it mean that it **does not work** if the affected documents are *on different shards*, meaning that it **does work** if the affected documents are *on the same shard*?

I have a sharded cluster but I can assure that all affected documents are on the same shard. So I want to know, if *in that case* I can use `$isolated`.

Comment: Possibly worth a code dig for a real answer, but this line grabs me immeditately: *"Prevents a write operation that affects multiple documents from yielding to other reads or writes once the first document is written"*. So a little lateral thinking would suggest that the selected documents in a collection would be held with a "write lock" (granularity depending on engine) which would therefore not make a lot of sense to go out and contact all shards and do this. I would err on the suspicion that once your connection was though `mongos` this is ignored completely.

Comment: I suppose the other test would be "what's in the logs on the shard members?". That would tell you if the `$isolated` option was passed through or stripped.

Comment: $isolated is guaranteed to work with non-sharding mongodb database instances. It is not guaranteed to work with shards and I am not quite sure if it should, considering the semantics of $isolated. It is still possible, but you've to invest a little bit more like implementing Two-Phase commits by crafting a sequence a sequence of changes that manipulate documents in a way that supports multi-document transactional behavior.

Comment: With some agreement from the client to certain conventions you can implement an $isolated behavior for sharded clusters, that is reliable and if written well resume- and recoverable.